# How to create multiple page by C# and ASP.NET in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am now trying to retrieve data from database and display all. But I would like to create multiple page link button to separate different sections (A, B, C...) of data, because my data is quite large amount. The image below is that result I would like to have.

Anyone could provide links or codes to help me on this?

[image: Example]

Comment: What ASP.NET control are you using to display your data? `GridView`? `ListView`?

Comment: @KarlAnderson I am trying to use the ASTreeView.. as I want to display all data in tree view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an asp.net repeater. It lets you bind a collection and create specific markup for each entry in the collection.

Here's an example:http://www.sitepoint.com/asp-net-repeater-control/